# Can't open a xdebug session with a vmware guest os?

Tags: xdebug, komodo

I've a vmware guest os with a webserver and xdebug 2.1.2 and I want to work from my host os with the remote debugger and Komodo IDE. How must I configure xdebug and Komodo to make it work? I've tried to add my host ip and my guest ip in the remote_host variable to no avail:

```
xdebug.remote_enable        On  
xdebug.remote_handler       dbgp
xdebug.remote_host          192.168.1.1 
xdebug.remote_log           /var/log/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_mode          req
xdebug.remote_port          9000
```

When I use the Komodo proxy option with the same address it gives me error no connection. Normaly I would use a reverse shell to tunnel my connection but this is a virtual machine on my localhost so I don't need a tunnel? Xdebug is loaded and I can change every variable and restart my webserver. I use Komodo remote ftp to load the php files I want to debug?

Edit: I can't telnet to port 9000 but I've forward my port to host port 9000:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The IP address in "xdebug.remote_host" needs to be the IP address of the machine where your IDE runs on. Make sure you can telnet to port 9000 on the machine where your IDE runs from the VM where PHP runs at. Do not use the Komodo proxy option, unless you have started the dbgpproxy yourself (which I doubt you have done). You should also upgrade Xdebug to the latest version.

Comment: I can't telnet to port 9000. How can I open it? I have Suse 12.2 but I've disabled my firewall. xdebug is loaded according to my phpinfo()?

Comment: xdebug.remote_host is my host ip and I can ping it from my guest. What is remote_handler? I don't have started a dbgpproxy myself?